# How to keep track of the network traffic on 3G/wifi on an iOS device?

Tags: ios, background, bandwidth

I am trying to understand how does an app like [DataMan](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dataman-real-time-data-usage/id393282873?mt=8) work. Even if it runs on the background, how can it measure the bandwidth allocation of the other apps?

Comment: I'm also trying to figure this out. Did you ever work it out?

Comment: No idea yet. I'll update this question if I learn something!

Comment: Here's the answer.   

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring/8014012#8014012

Answer (score 3):

Most apps like that inject a proxy to all your data calls.  Through that they measure the amount of bandwidth you are consuming.

There is no way to measure data you are using outside of your app. You can track it for your own network call within your app though.

Comment: I am looking to track usage of data sent and received through my app. I would really appreciate your help if you could please give some suggestion on how to do it. Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14450656/427969